# Play 2.2 - Enumeratee[List[E], E] = enumerate through list of elements element by element

Tags: scala, playframework-2.2, enumerator

How to transform an `Enumerator[List[E]]` to act like an `Enumerator[E]` ?

First, I think about `Enumeratee[From, To]`, but I only found documentation about mapping or filtering.

Is it possible with an `Enumeratee` to split a `List[E]` into multiple `E` ?

Comment: I'd probably just write `myEnumerator flatMap enumerate` (after having imported `enumerate` from `Enumerator`). If you really want an `Enumeratee` I'm not sure it's going to get much better than your version below.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, but indeed, I need an `Enumeratee` in my design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something that works but IMHO, it is a workaround.

```
def flatEnumeratee[To] = Enumeratee.mapConcat[List[To]](identity)
```

I thought that something will be provided without the need of specified the identity function.